# Multiple EditText objects in AlertDialog

Tags: android, google-maps, dialog, android-edittext

I'm working on a project for college that will let a user place a point on a map and then set the title and description for the overlay object. The problem is, the second `EditText` box overwrites the first one. Here is my code for the dialog box.

```
//Make new Dialog
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mapView.getContext());
dialog.setTitle("Set Target Title & Description");
dialog.setMessage("Title: ");

final EditText titleBox = new EditText(mapView.getContext());
dialog.setView(titleBox);

dialog.setMessage("Description: ");
final EditText descriptionBox = new EditText(mapView.getContext());
dialog.setView(descriptionBox);
```

Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 111, accepted):

A Dialog only contains one root View, that's why `setView()` overwrites the first EditText.  The solution is simple put everything in one ViewGroup, for instance a LinearLayout:

```
Context context = mapView.getContext();
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

// Add a TextView here for the "Title" label, as noted in the comments
final EditText titleBox = new EditText(context);
titleBox.setHint("Title");
layout.addView(titleBox); // Notice this is an add method

// Add another TextView here for the "Description" label
final EditText descriptionBox = new EditText(context);
descriptionBox.setHint("Description");
layout.addView(descriptionBox); // Another add method

dialog.setView(layout); // Again this is a set method, not add
```

(This is a basic example, but it should get you started.)

You should take note of the nomenclature difference between a `set` and `add` method. `setView()` only holds one View, the same is similar for `setMessage()`.  In fact this should be true for every `set` method, what you're thinking of are `add` commands.  `add` methods are cumulative, they build a list of everything you push in while `set` methods are singular, they replace the existing data.

Comment: Ah that's brilliant thank you, exactly what I was looking for, one question, is there any way to put writing above each text box? Like "Title:" then "Description:" ??

Comment: @Tomcelic yes you can do it, just add in order a TextView, EditText,TextViewand finally  an EditText, but I think using the layoutInflator would be better

Comment: `LinearLayout.VERTICAL` OMG I was going to throw everything out from the window yelling in agony!!!

Answer (score 19):

You can build your layout that contains two EditText, inflate it with a `LayoutInflater` and use that as the View of your `AlertDialog`.

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);

//text_entry is an Layout XML file containing two text field to display in alert dialog
final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.text_entry, null);

final EditText input1 = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
final EditText input2 = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.EditText2);


input1.setText("DefaultValue", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
input2.setText("DefaultValue", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setIcon(R.drawable.icon).setTitle("EntertheText:").setView(textEntryView).setPositiveButton("Save",
  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
     int whichButton) {

    Log.i("AlertDialog","TextEntry 1 Entered "+input1.getText().toString());
    Log.i("AlertDialog","TextEntry 2 Entered "+input2.getText().toString());
    /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
   }
  }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",
  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
     int whichButton) {
     /*
     * User clicked cancel so do some stuff
     */
   }
  });
alert.show();
```

[image]

you can add your EditText programmatically too like this:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mapView.getContext());
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

final EditText titleBox = new EditText(mapView.getContext());
titleBox.setHint("Title");
layout.addView(titleBox);

final EditText descriptionBox = new EditText(mapView.getContext());
descriptionBox.setHint("Description");
layout.addView(descriptionBox);

dialog.setView(layout);
```

Comment: Seriously, every answer should contains a picture of the result. I googled for something like this. And I saw this pic. Immediately clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    alert.setTitle("Buy Airtime")
    alert.setMessage("Enter phone details and amount to buy airtime.")

    val layout = LinearLayout(this)
    layout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL

    val mobileNoET = EditText(this)
    mobileNoET.setSingleLine()
    mobileNoET.hint = "Mobile Number"
    layout.addView(mobileNoET)

    val amountET = EditText(this)
    amountET.setSingleLine()
    amountET.hint = "Amount"
    layout.addView(amountET)

    val networkET = EditText(this)
    networkET.setSingleLine()
    networkET.hint = "Network"
    layout.addView(networkET)

    layout.setPadding(50, 40, 50, 10)

    alert.setView(layout)

    alert.setPositiveButton("Proceed") { _, _ ->
        val mobileNo = mobileNoET.text.toString()
        val amount = amountET.text.toString()
        val network = networkET.text.toString()

        Log.i("xxx",mobileNo )
        Log.i("xxx",amount )
        Log.i("xxx",network )

        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    alert.setCancelable(false)
    alert.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Code for create a popup with two EditText using Xamarin

```
    public void dial()
    {

        AlertDialog alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).Create();
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

                   layout.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;


        EditText factinput = new EditText(this);
        alerta.SetMessage("Facturas Disponibles:");
        layout.AddView(factinput);

        EditText canttinput = new EditText(this);
        alerta.SetMessage("Cantidad:");
        layout.AddView(canttinput);

        alerta.SetView(layout);


        alerta.SetButton("Cancelar", (a, b) =>
        {

            AlertDialog cencelacion = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).Create();
            cencelacion.SetMessage("Desea Cancelar");
            cencelacion.SetButton("OK", (c, d) => { });
            cencelacion.Show();

        });
        alerta.SetButton2("Aceptar", (ee, f) =>
        {
            AlertDialog confirmacion = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).Create();
            confirmacion.SetMessage("Realizar Busqueda de Factura");
            confirmacion.SetButton("OK", (c, d) => { });
            confirmacion.Show();
        }
        );

        alerta.Show();

    }
```